# Combinatorics of classifying objects.

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

Given a multiset of $n$ primes (with product of multiset less than $2^{n\log n}$) how many ways can we assemble them into $k$ composite number of equal size?

I am looking for asymptotics.

Comment: It looks like what you're after are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: even for $k=2$?

Comment: Sure, the only restriction is $0\le k \le n$.

Comment: @EuYu Are you certain it's not $1 \leq k \leq n$?

Comment: @Arthur Right, $k$ should be positive. Too used to binomial coefficients I guess.

Comment: Do the groups have labels?

Comment: @AndréNicolas this is actual problem so if you have $n$ factors of a number how many way can you partition them into $2$ groups. Is there any label here?

Comment: @Student: I don't know, would have to know about the motivating problem. For $k=2$ the problems are not *very* different. Where the labeled/unlabeled makes a difference is with two groups of the same size.

Comment: @AndréNicolas yeah the two groups have same size.

Comment: @Student:  With little information about the actual problem. an answer has to be of a general and therefore probably useless character.  But if you are dividing into groups of equal size, we are looking at $\binom{n}{n/2}$ or half of it, and there are very good asymptotics for that.

Comment: @AndréNicolas updated.